# How can I color my code on Stack Overflow when posting an answer?

Tags: colors

How can I color my code on Stack Overflow when posting an answer? How should I format my code?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Select your code and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Also add your language as a **tag** in your question or answer

Comment: use `<!-- language-all: cpp -->` to set language of code in general. replace `cpp` with your desire language. [full description Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Comment: I am always searching for this document when i enter code into stack overflow. *how again was the syntax for coloring this code?* I wished that when i press the *insert code* button it would be more helpful than just indenting the code.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "add your language as a tag in your answer"? is it possible to tag answers?

Answer (score -2):

Whenever you can edit a post, there's a question-mark icon above the text area. Press that and get [all the editing information goodness you can hope for](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

To indicate some code, simply indent it with 4 spaces:

```
for q in question:
    answer(q)
```

Comment: I think this question should be merged to meta. What do you think?

Comment: @Harry: I agree, that's why I voted to close. In the meantime, giving an answer doesn't hurt ;-)